# Как правильно указывать <data> в <intent-filter>?

Tags: android

У меня есть Intent:

```
Intent captureImage = new Intent("qwer");
captureImage.setData(uri);
startActivity(captureImage);
```

Значение uri:`content://com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.fileprovider/crime-photos/name-of-photo.jpg`

Мой `<intent-filter>` в активности другого приложения:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="qwer"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

**Вопрос:** как должен выглядеть тэг `<data>` в этом `<intent-filter>`, чтобы `startActivity(captureImage)` нашёл данную активность ?

Comment: Маловато информации по условиям фильтра. Активность своего же приложения, содержимое которого вам заранее известно можно запустить по пакету и имени класса. Если она должна обрабатывать запросы и от сторонних приложений, то не ясно что именно она шарит. Для начала нужно указать хотя бы схему: `android:scheme="content"` или тип: `android:mimeType="*/*"` (указание типа автоматически включает схемы `content` и `file`)

Comment: @woesss схему указал, а дальше как ? нужно указать authority, но в `<data>` такого атрибута нету. Есть `android:host` и `android:port`, которые являются частями authority. В `android:host` записал `com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.fileprovider`. Потом нужен path. Записал в `android:path` `/crime-photos`. Активность не находит.

Comment: Как вам ответить, если вы так и не сказали что вы от этого фильтра хотите? `authority` является идентификатором вашего приложения и вместо его указания проще и правильнее запускать конкретную активность явным интентом (по имени класса как при переходе внутри приложения) и для этого фильтр вообще не требуется

Comment: @woesss я не могу воспользоваться явным интентом потому что та активность, которую я хочу запустить, находится в другом пакете, а не в моём приложении.

Comment: Но вы же знаете его пакет и имя класса - ничто не мешает этим воспользоваться: `intent.setClassName("other.app.package.name", "activity.full.class.Name")`. Кроме того в неявном интенте тег `<data>` не обязателен и для запуска достаточно одного единственного экшена. Всё остальное добавляется для отсечения нежелательных запросов, которые активность не может/не хочет/не должна обрабатывать.